# Joining tables without getting the unmatched records

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, db2

I have the below two tables (one & two) and need the output as in the third table.

```
ONE  

ID    TAG
1     A
2     B
3     c

TWO

ID TAG
1  A
2  Z  

OUTPUT  

ID  TAG  
1   A  
3   C
```

Conditions -
1. Need the values for which the 'TAG' matches
2. Need the values from 'ONE' which are not available in the 'TWO' table
3. Do no need the values for which the 'TAG' does not match

Can this be done in a single SQL query?

Comment: Why is C in the output? It doesn't match.

Comment: A normal `INNER JOIN` does what you describe in the conditions. Please show what you tried, and explain why it doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [**`LEFT JOIN`**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) keeps the unmatched result from the first table:

```
SELECT one.id AS id, one.tag AS tag
FROM   one LEFT JOIN two ON one.id = two.id
WHERE  one.tag = two.tag OR two.tag IS NULL;
```

The first condition `one.tag = two.tag` gets the matching result; the second `two.tag IS NULL` gets what are available in table `one` but not `two`.

Checkout the [**demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0661/1). Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.ID, a.TAG
from ONE a LEFT OUTER JOIN TWO b
ON (a.ID = b.ID
and a.TAG = b.TAG)
```